# "Program has stopped working" but it works normally

Tags: c++, windows, qt, crash

I have a very weird problem. Original program worked fine but now a small update of the program is crashing for a single user but it works normally for everyone else.

Basically, as soon as he starts the program he get's windows error message "Program X has stopped working" and the dump:

> Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
>   Application Name: programname.exe
>   Application Version: 0.0.0.1
>   Application Timestamp: 535ceb8c
>   Fault Module Name: programname.exe
>   Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.1
>   Fault Module Timestamp: 535ceb8c
>   Exception Code: c000001d
>   Exception Offset: 004a5542
>   OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
>   Locale ID: 2057
>   Additional Information 1: ac38
>   Additional Information 2: ac387466df76c7f98f034212b24686d7
>   Additional Information 3: 23ca
>   Additional Information 4: 23cafe810bbb46d87a7f0938a06eb3ea

Once he closes the error dialog **the program starts up normally and works without any problems**. Nobody else has this issue so I suspect it might also be OS/setup related.

The program does not even do anything really (on startup) it's just a simple UI. So it crashes even before it comes to my actual code.

Built with:
-Qt 5.1.0
-msvc 2010
-guest OS is Windows 7

Code that presumably executes:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/favicon.ico"));
    w.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Mainwindow constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);

    isStartupUpdate=true;
    ismax=false;
}
```

Any guidelines on how to approach and debug this?

Comment: Well, show the code and also what change you have made, please.

Comment: I've seen this happen to VLC on Windows 7, so maybe it's a problem with the OS rather than your application.

Comment: You mean Windows OS update by "small update"?

Comment: @Laszlo Papp: Added main() and Mainwindow constructor. I don't think anything else actually executes. I have a few mouse handling events to re-implement some window functionality but I don't think those are of any importance.

Comment: By small update I mean that I updated the program with a few lines of code.

Comment: I was notified that AV might have been the problem. After AV was disabled the error went away. I'll wait some more time for confirmation.

Comment: What is AV? Some Anti-Virus software? Which few lines of code did you change?

Comment: Yes, antivirus (avast). I didn't actually change any line that would affect program startup. That's why it was so weird to me.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same thing happen to me on c#

I added `Debugger.Break();` and thats where it showed the Application stopped working. This should not happen as far as I know.

I changed to

```
#if DEBUG 
Debugger.Break();
#endif
```

to fix this & works now